# Option.order is broken when passing it to class method

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

### Background

```
Error: Order must be type of array or instance of a valid sequelize method
```

I thought I've solved this issue but turns out that I mess up with this error again.

I'm trying to make class method to calculate some properties for a model.
Let this be Model A.

Model A is associated with Model B. Because I have issue for generating proper column name for Model B when using array parameter.
I'm planning to bypass this issue by using `sequelize.literal()`

---

### Pattern

1. Make a class method for Model A (a lot of business layer is used this function. So I can't take this away)
2. Prototype of this method is `Model.function(options)`. This options object is validated inside of method function and if it needed mutated somehow.
3. Validated option object is passed to  `Model.findAll(options)`

I'm impletmenting this solution as like code below

### Router

```js
const sequelize = require('sequelize')
const { ModelA } = require('../models')
...
router.get('/', ..., async (req, res, next) => {
    try {
        ...
        if(page < lastpage + 1){
            const products = await ModelA.classMethod({
                subquery : false,
                include: [
                   ...
                ],
                ...
                order : sequelize.literal(`"Product.rating" DESC`)
            })
            
            ...
        }
        ...
    } catch (e) {
        ...
    }
})
```

### Class method

```
ModelA.classMethod = async function(options){
   const sequelize = require('sequelize')
   const { ModelB } = require('.')

   let { include, where, order, limit, offset, product } = options
    ...

    const items = await ModelA.findAll({
      subquery: false,
      include: [
        {
          model: ModelB,
          as: 'ModelB',
          required: true,
          where: product.where,
          include: include
        }
      ],
      where: where,
      limit: limit,
      order: order
    })

    ...
}
```

Weird thing is happening here. While passing parameter (Pattern 3), I got an error `Error: Order must be type of array or instance of a valid sequelize method` and this error seems that because the option passed is invalid `sequelize.literal()`

But actually what I passed is just `` sequelize.literal(`'Product.name' DESC`) ``, no mutation in here.
So I tried to figure out what's wrong with my literal.

```
let { order } = option

console.log(order)//Literal { val: "'Product.rating' DESC" }
console.log(order instanceof sequelize.Utils.SequelizeMethod)//false

if(!order) order = null

console.log(order)//Literal { val: "'Product.rating' DESC" }

ModelA.findAll({ ..., order : order })

console.log('good!!!')//I want to see this log
```

Order itself looks fine but I think somewhere of prototype is broken.
The most weired part is if I replace the order with `` sequelize.literal(`'Product.name' DESC`) ``
,which is the same as what I passed into classMethod parameter, some kind of magic happens and error is gone.

```
const sequelize = require('sequelize')
let order = sequelize.literal("'Product.rating'")

console.log(order)//Literal { val: "'Product.rating' DESC" }
console.log(order instanceof sequelize.Utils.SequelizeMethod)//true!!

if(!order) order = null

ModelA.findAll({ ..., order : order })

console.log('good!!!')//I see this log and I can finally rest in peace.
```

---

If anyone has similar problem like me, would you please share some insight to solve this problem? So far I tried like below.

1. Passing router sequelize instance to class method. `console.log(order instanceof sequelize.Utils.SequelizeMethod)//true`  so seems not broken actual query is not executed somehow.
2. Statically add `order : sequelize.literal("'Product.rating' DESC")` : work perfect but useless in production. This option should be dynanic so that user can control it.

Answer (score 0):

**My bad** What were weird was not the error but me using different version between applications and project root. This problem is caused by **version issue with nested directory**.

```
/* MY PROJECT STRUCTURE */

project
|
|--api (sequelize 5.22)
|
|--auth
|
|--batch
|
|-- models (sequelize 6.3)
```

Recently, I upgraded sequelize from 5.22 to 6.3 while doing that, I missed upgrading sequelize of the applications. So the version between root and applications were being different. Since migration to typescript is on going in sequelize, sequelize inner types of 6.0 and 5.22 must be different.

`Error: Order must be type of array or instance of a valid sequelize method`

So that, this error was reasonable enough but I couldn't get that at the moment. There are many advices not to install same module in nested directory. I should've listened to them carefully.

---

But still, ordering with array (ex > `[model, 'column', 'type']`) gives me wrong query and ended up with unknown column error.